# how to load a svg in gwt widget from an url

Tags: gwt, svg

I have a servlet that delivers png and svg images. With png i have no problem:

```
Image image = new Image(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + token);
```

But how to get svg to work? I already added "lib-gwt-svg" to my dependencies. There is a SVGImage class:

```
SVGImage svg = new SVGImage(OMSVGParser.parse(???));
```

The parse takes a string. Is there a way to load a raw String from an URL?

Or how to get it to work (with or without "lib-gwt-svg")?

**Update:**
thx to Andrei Volgin: he pointed out that it should work with "Image" and it does (i just had to correct the mime type to "image/svg+xml"). But the scripts within svg-image don't work this way (it looks like the images is rendered as a normal bitmap image).
I need the image rendered as svg (with scripts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works without any external library (like Andrei's Solution) but keeps also the embedded scripts working. I used the info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592024/how-to-get-rid-of-double-scrollbars-on-internal-frame-of-gwt-app) - i used a HTMLPanel and loaded the image via "RequestBuilder":

```
    String url = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + link.getToken();
    RequestBuilder rB = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);
    rB.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
            //create Widget
            chartImage = new HTMLPanel(response.getText());
            //add to layout   
            layout.add(chartImage);

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use a URL to load an image, you don't need any libraries at all. And you don't need a servlet to deliver them. Just add images to your /war/images folder. Then, in your GWT code:

```
Image image = new Image();
image.setUrl("images/myImage.svg");
myPanel.add(image);
```

You may want to add some logic for browsers that do not support svg files.

Comment: thx this is working nearly perfect: but for some reason the scripts within the svg (hover effects) doesn't work.
(on inspecting the generated code i can't see the svg code - it looks like i added a normal image)