# How to create an gwt widget for svg image properly?

Tags: gwt

I know how to load svg-images into gwt: [last answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858907/how-to-load-a-svg-in-gwt-widget-from-an-url)

with this i just trying to create a "SvgImage" class. It should work like gwt's image(url):
I could add the image independent of loading state and as soon the loading is finished the image becomes visible.
how to achieve this?(i tried to read image' sources but it is terrible - neither can't find the place where url is loaded nor where the LoadEvent is fired)

Or in general what is a good approach to create widgets that loads their contents via a given url?

Comment: could you post some code about how you are creating the SvgImage, how you add it to the dom,  and whether you are setting the LoadEvent ?

Answer (score 0):

i dug a liitle bit in gwt image source and found that there is "replaceElement(Node)" - a protected method especially made for image but this method is based on

```
Widget.getElement().replaceChild(newElement, oldElement);
```

Here is my complete SvgWidget class:

```
public class SvgWidget implements IsWidget {

    private String svgUrl;
    private ADBTexte strings;
    private IsWidget thisW;
    private Loading loadingWidget;

    @Inject
    private SvgWidget(@Assisted final String svgUrl, final ADBTexte strings, final Loading loadingWidget) {
        this.svgUrl = svgUrl;
        this.strings = strings;
        this.loadingWidget = loadingWidget;

    }

    @Override
    public Widget asWidget() {
        thisW = new SimplePanel(loadingWidget);
        RequestBuilder rB = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, svgUrl);
        rB.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(final Request request, final Response response) {
                Widget result = new HTML(response.getText());
                thisW.asWidget()
                     .getElement()
                     .replaceChild(result.getElement(), thisW.asWidget().getElement().getChild(0));
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(final Request request, final Throwable exception) {
                Widget result = new Label(strings.chartError());
                thisW.asWidget()
                     .getElement()
                     .replaceChild(result.getElement(), thisW.asWidget().getElement().getChild(0));
                GWT.log("Error on loading chart: ", exception);

            }
        });
        try {
            rB.send();
        } catch (RequestException e) {
            Widget result = new Label(strings.chartError());
            thisW.asWidget().getElement().replaceChild(result.getElement(), thisW.asWidget().getElement().getChild(0));
            GWT.log("Error on sending request for chart: ", e);
        }

        return thisW.asWidget();
    }

    /**
     * Use this to get an instance of {@link SvgWidget}.
     * 
     */
    public interface Factory {
        /**
         * 
         * @param svgUrl
         *            url for svg graphic
         * @return instance of {@link SvgWidget} displaying the svg accessible via the given url
         */
        SvgWidget get(@Assisted String svgUrl);
    }

}
```

The relevant stuff is in asWidget(). But i am unsure if this is a good/ the best solution:

- is SimplePanel a good container (i only need the container to replace an element)
- probably i should implement HasLoadHandlers?!
- the widget displays a loading widget - probably it is better placed
- something else to take into account?

(for those who don't know dependency injection (with gin): ignore all unknown annotations and the factory interfce)