# gwt how to fire own loadevent

Tags: events, gwt

I created a widget that displays svg images. Including a browser fork to display a png alternatively.

In case of loading the `png` I am using `Image` class and refire its loading event. 
The `svg-xml` String is fetched from server via `RequestBuilder` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230972/how-to-create-an-gwt-widget-for-svg-image-properly)). Now I want to fire a new `LoadEvent` `onResponseReceived` and an `ErrorEvent` `onError`.

But how to create a `LoadEvent` (Javadoc says I should create one from a `NativeEvent` but this doesn't have a constructor either).

The only way I see at the moment is to create my own `LoadEvent`, but this shouldn't be necessary, should it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NativeEvent loadEvent = Document.get().createLoadEvent();
DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(loadEvent, source);
```

Replacing `source` with your widget.

The same with `Document.get().createErrorEvent()` for the error event.