# Displaying svg file in gwt

Tags: gwt, svg

I am new to gwt and in my application I have to display a svg file which I get from server.
The question is I am able to get the svg file from server side and display using HTMLPanel.
But events are not getting fired.Like mouse over ,drag and drop events etc which are inside
the svg file they are not getting fired.
Please let me know how can I solve this issue.

below is my code
image = new HTMLPanel(response.getText());
rootPanel.add(image);

Thanks in advance,
Pradeep

Comment: 1) could you show your code, in which you try to fire and handle the mouse events? 2) If you are adding the whole svg structure as a text, the elements are not treated as any GWT objects, just plain html, so no event handlers are attached.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,What I read from below link is we dont need to write any mouse over events explicitly in gwt.The events which there in svg file will be get triggered.So I have not wrote any event handlers.Yes you are right the whole svg file  is treated as some text.So how can I solve?                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858907/how-to-load-a-svg-in-gwt-widget-from-an-url

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to display the SVG XML or a Data URI as HTML? If so, that text will not generate any events, only the `HTMLPanel` will. The following code should allow you to add a handler to the `HTMLPanel`:

```java
image.addDomHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Mouse over");
    }
}, MouseOverEvent.getType());
```

Attach other event handlers the same way.